# How to close google chrome via C#?

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome

1. I want to close Google chrome via C#. Help me!
2. I want to Written c# control Google chrome by control open/close Google chrome

Comment: Please include a sample of the code you've tried so far.

Comment: You should search for your options, then attempt one of them, rather than just asking us to write your code for you.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your requirements. Do you have a question or is this just a request for code?

Answer (score 7):

Use [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9(v=vs.110).aspx) class to get all Chrome processes in an array, and then just kill them all.

```
Process [] chromeInstances = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");

foreach(Process p in chromeInstances)
    p.Kill();
```

Answer (score 0):

A hint to the task is to use the `Process` class and send a `WM_CLOSE` message to the window. Rest of the code after you show some effort. :)